# Setting Up Bootstrap on Rails for the First Time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, installation

I'm trying to implement Bootstrap (for the first time) to my ***very*** simple rails application.
After following common setup instructions the app's look has not changed

The app is located here:
https://github.com/johnwaltonvi/omrails2

My initial setup went as followed... 
1. Add bootstrap gem to "Gemfile" 
2. Run "bundle install"
3. Create new file under app>assets>stylesheets. 
This file is called "styles.css.scss"
4. Add "@import 'bootstrap';" to "styles.css.scss" 
5. Restart Server

After starting up the app again, it still looks the exact same as before installing bootstrap.

**I expected bootstrap to overwrite the font, text & links.**
In this picture is what the app currently looks like (left) and what it should look like (right).

[image]

Why has the app not updated style?

Notes: 
I'm following instructions from One Month Rails video course.

Comment: Follow instructions closely here https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

Answer (score 0):

Rails 4 doesn't support the :assets group so change this:

```
group :assets do
   gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
   gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
   gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.3'
   gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
end
```

to this:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
```

Rerun `bundle install` to make sure everything is installed.

Rename your application.css file to application.css.scss and delete everything in the file. Now add this to it:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Everything should work if you do this.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response sir. I did exactly as you instructed and the problem persists. I'm doing this on windows if that helps. Updated Gemfile, renamed application.css.scss. Still I do not see bootstrap working... The github page above reflects these changes. Still searching for an answer on the internet.

Comment: @John In the <head> section of your application.html.erb file are you linking the application stylesheet with `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>`?